# Unable to access sites during a SharePoint DR test

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, content-database, disaster-recovery, database-attach

Our company does not have hot DR site for our SharePoint environment.  So we are using the process to restore the data to our DR site:

1. Create all site collections in DR pointing to the same ContentDatabase name as it's counterpart in production (example if: http://prodsite/teams/team1 was pointing to PRD_ContentDB3 then we setup http://drsite/teams/team1 to point to PRD_ContentDB3 on the DR SQL Server).
2. Detatch and then delete the databases created in #1.
3. Restore production databases to the DR SQL Server.  Update all security on the databases to match production, but using the DR accounts.
4. Ran Powershell to re-attatch the database to SharePoint.

We are setup with CLAIMS authentication.

Once the restore was done, we could not connect to the sites that existed in production.  Every site returns an error: "**Sorry, something went wrong.  File not Found**.  If I create a new site collection in a new content database it works fine.  If I create a new site collection in a DB from prod it works, but anything that existed in prod will not work (including the root).

We have a DB alias setup that matches production (except points to the DR SQL server).  Has anyone else had this before?  Have I missed a step somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are we talking about two different farms or one farm with two Web app? or two farms but single sql server

Comment: The DR environment is a separate farm (SharePoint and SQL) entirely.

Comment: ok, just for understanding the issue....you restored the DB from production to DR farm....after that you are getting the file not found error  in DR farm not Production, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  (thanks for responding BTW).  Production is fine.  The DB came from Production to the DR site.  Once restored trying to access under the DR URL is not working, however new sites created are accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Your DR scenario, you have two independent farm. I would recommend the following steps.

- Setup the DR farm same as Prod Farm( which i believe you have).
- Now Create the web app and configure the same authentication etc.
- Now take the backup the content database from Production sql server
- Restore the database on the DR farm and attached to the web app.
- From central admin > application management >view all site collections... check all your production sites are here. also make sure root level site collection is their.."/".

Note: no need to create the site collections in advance, as you are restoring the DB it will take care of it.

Comment: So you are saying that I should copy over the config database too?  Otherwise, that won't work since the location of the site collections is located in the config DB.  If I just copied over the Content DB, the config DB wouldn't know the site collections are now available.

Comment: Not config, only content..once u attached the db to sharepoint farm...config will get all the information during that attachments process

Comment: Also last thing which I mentioned check CA if all site collections are their r nto

Comment: Ok, so one more question if you don't mind.  When you say setup DR the same as prod, do you mean that I need to set it up with the same accounts?  We have special accounts for DR.  Also, would I have to set the webapp with the same URL?  I am trying to set it up so that Prod and DR each have their own distinct URL

Comment: Same refer to...same version / build numbers...i.e if ur prod is on July cu 2015 then ur dr should be same cu level....you don't need the same url..it is conflicting with prod n cause outage....for service account, you need to make sure dr Web app pool n farm admin account had DBO rights on restored db.

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try and report back.  Basically what you are asking me to do is what I have done already, except to not pre-create the site collections.  Both farms are at the exact same build and the accounts have the same access.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: That's how the restore / move to different farm works....best of luck

Comment: Hi Waqas, Thanks for your help yesterday, but I am afraid it isn't working.  I followed your instructions.  Before I remounted the DBs I created a root site and confirmed it responded.  Once I confirmed it worked, I deleted it and attached all the backed up content databases.  I then confirmed they existed in CA.  However, accessing any of the sites results in Sorry, something went wrong.  File not Found.

Comment: That's weird, can you see root site collection from central admin? How many site collections in restored db? Do you have any custom solution deployed in you prod environment, which are not present in dr farm? Check the event logs n uls logs for more details....also directly try to browse the settings page of site collection.../_layouts/settings.aspx

Comment: So actually I found out the databases were just fine.  The issue was the databases contained solutions that had not deployed properly.

I ran Test-SPContentDatabase on the databases being restored to the DR site.  It turns out that our custom code did not deploy properly.  I reattached the databases, redeployed our code and the DR site responds fine.

What's frustrating is that I was sure the code was there properly.  Thanks for your help Waqas.

Comment: great...that was my feeling...that's why i asked do u have any custom solution.